# Ruby: begin rescue block not working properly

Tags: ruby, rescue

Below `begin-rescue` block in `hooks.rb` is not working properly. When there is "results" directory available it goes to `rescue` block and when it is not it goes to `begin` block. Sounds funny but this is what happening.

Now when I use same `begin-rescue` in separate ruby file it works like charm. Runs `begin` when directory available and runs `rescue` when it is not.

Tell you about "results" directory it appears after test completion, automatically because I am using `pretty_face` gem. It has few sub directories like "images" and "stylesheets".

**hooks.rb**

```
require 'fileutils'


def delete_results
  FileUtils.remove_dir(File.join(File.absolute_path('../..', File.dirname(__FILE__)),"results"))
end


  Before do
    begin
      delete_results
    rescue
      puts "cant delete results dir or it doesnt exist"
    end
  end
```

I also tried it in separate ruby file which always work:
**delete_dir.rb**

```
require 'fileutils'

begin
  FileUtils.remove_dir(File.join(File.absolute_path('../..', File.dirname(__FILE__)),"results"))
rescue
  puts "cant delete results dir or it doesnt exist"
end
```

Error when dir exists but `begin` block in hooks.rb doesn't work

```
File exists - results\images (Errno::EEXIST)
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in `mkdir'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:247:in `fu_mkdir'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:221:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:219:in `reverse_each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:219:in `block in mkdir_p'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:205:in `each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/1.9.1/fileutils.rb:205:in `mkdir_p'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pretty_face-0.10.3/lib/pretty_face/formatter/html.rb:188:in `make_directory'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pretty_face-0.10.3/lib/pretty_face/formatter/html.rb:182:in `make_output_directories'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pretty_face-0.10.3/lib/pretty_face/formatter/html.rb:63:in `before_features'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:181:in `block in send_to_all'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:179:in `each'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:179:in `send_to_all'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:169:in `broadcast'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/ast/tree_walker.rb:20:in `visit_features'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:49:in `run!'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:47:in `execute!'
C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/cucumber-1.3.17/bin/cucumber:13:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby193/bin/cucumber:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby193/bin/cucumber:23:in `<top (required)>'
-e:1:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'

Process finished with exit code 1
Empty test suite.
```

The error is coming because due to some reason (which I don't know) it couldn't delete the directory because "images" and "stylesheets" subdir were present in "results" dir. So I deleted them manually so that `begin` block work. Now above error is not there and it skips the `begin` block and goes to `rescue` block and prints "cant delete results dir or it doesn't exist" though "results" dir is there.

Comment: You meant exception thrown by `delete_results` method not being handled by rescue ? If so, can you tell me the exception name is being thrown by the `delete_results` method.

Comment: To the Person who is downvoting >> do you know the solution? If not then do not discourage other developers by down voting, to put efforts in this question.

Comment: Would you do `puts File.join(File.absolute_path('../..', File.dirname(__FILE__)),"results")` and copy the result here.

Comment: How does the implementation of `Before` look like? Where is is defined?

Comment: @mudasobwa it gives the absolute path of "results" dir and @ spickermann it is Before method that instantiate browser before commencing the tests. In-fact you can put anything that you want in Before which you want to access before tests start.